# How to choose values from col1 if their values are in col2 but not on list in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1       | description
---------- |-----------
John Simon |John Simon red
Terry Juk  |green Terry Juk
John Bravo |John Bravo brown
Ann Still  |orange Ann Still

bad_list = ["red", "green"]
```

And I need to select only these people from "col1" which have value from "col" in column "description" and something else (nevermind before or after), but it something else could not be from bad_list.

So I need to select only John Bravo and Ann Still because they have their value from "col1" in column "description" and does not have words from bad_list with their name in column "description".

How to do that in Python Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
bad_list = ["red", "green"]

mask = df["description"].str.contains(r"|".join(bad_list))
print(df.loc[~mask, "col1"])
```

Prints:

```
2    John Bravo
3     Ann Still
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

---

EDIT: To check if value from `col1` is in description:

```py
bad_list = ["red", "green"]

mask1 = df["description"].str.contains(r"|".join(bad_list))
mask2 = df.apply(lambda x: x["col1"] in x["description"], axis=1)
print(df.loc[~mask1 & mask2, "col1"])
```

---

EDIT2: To ignore case:

```py
import re

bad_list = ["RED", "green"]

mask1 = df["description"].str.contains(r"|".join(bad_list), flags=re.I)
mask2 = df.apply(lambda x: x["col1"] in x["description"], axis=1)
print(df.loc[~mask1 & mask2, "col1"])
```

Comment: I think you missed a point where value from col1 should be present in description

Comment: Andrej Kesely, nice job! best answer! But my the way, is it possible to also manage the size of letter in bad list? because sometimes I can have "RED" or "red" or "Red" ? how to deal with it ?

Comment: @gato See my EDIT2

Comment: thank you! perfect! I gave best answer definitely!!

Comment: Andrej Kesely, but one more thing, If I can.... because I checked and it is not ideally, because for example if I have in "col1" John Bravo, so I need to also have John Bravo + something else in "description, but it something else could not be an elements from bad list, nevertheless using your solution if I for example will have sentence "Bravo" in bad list it will not select John Bravo, I do not want to have for example "Bravo John Bravo: but I want to have for example "John Bravo rock" do you understand? I 1. if col is  in description then I also analyse "something else" in term of bad list

Comment: @gato To not clutter the comment section I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'll try to look at it.

Comment: Andrej Kesely, so in steps: 1. value from col1 is in description with something else before or after? great! 2. check whether "something else" is on bad list, it is? drop it, is not? select it. Because as I mentionded above, If I have in col1 - John Bravo, in description - Bravo John Bravo and in bad_list "Bravo" it will drop this record, do you understand ?

Comment: Ok Andrej I will create new question and give link for you there for a moment

Comment: Andrej Kesely, I modify this question on this link, could you check it as we told about it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135863/complex-analysis-of-values-in-two-columns-in-python-pandas

Comment: Andrej Kesely, could you check link above? I described my problem with your solution