# Complex analysis of values in two columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
col1       | description
---------- |-----------
John Simon |John Simon red
Terry Juk  |green Terry Juk
John Bravo |brown John Bravo 
Ann Still  |orange Ann Still


bad_list = ["JOHN", "green"]
```

And I need to select only these people from "col1" which have value from "col" in column "description" and something else (nevermind before or after), but it something else could not be from bad_list.

I used code like below:

```
import re

bad_list = ["JOHN", "green"]

mask1 = df["description"].str.contains(r"|".join(bad_list), flags=re.I)
mask2 = df.apply(lambda x: x["col1"] in x["description"], axis=1)
print(df.loc[~mask1 & mask2, "col1"])
```

Nevertheless, If I have situation like in the third (3) row that value in col1 = "John Bravo" and description is "brown John Bravo" and in bad_list I have value "JOHN", above code will drop third row of this data frame, because this code will find in description sentence from bad_list ("JOHN"), nevertheless bad_list NOT concernes values from col1 which are in column description, bad_list concerns only "something else". I want so as to code analyze like this:

1. Is value + something else (before or after this value) from col1 in description?
2. Analyse "something else" (for instance for third row something elese is "brown" because it is not in col1, but together with the value from col1 are in the description column) if it is on bad_list -> drop row, if "something else" is not on bad_list -> stay row

So, third row "John Bravo" should stay because ok, John is in bad list, but checking bad list concerns only to checking "something else" in description column, "something else" is value which is concatenated with value from col1 and these values are in description column together.

So, from this Data Frame should be ONLY dropped: second row Terry Juk because "something else" of this rows is on bad list ("green").

How to do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see this guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question includes a lot of details which are specific to your case, but not really programming related. Please try to really simplify your question and condense it down to one specific issue you're facing. If you have lots of overlapping issues you're wrestling with, feel free to post multiple questions using examples narrowly targeting each issue. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

bad_list = ["JOHN", "green"]

mask1 = df.apply(lambda x: x["col1"] in x["description"], axis=1)
tmp = df.apply(lambda x: x["description"].replace(x["col1"], ""), axis=1)
mask2 = tmp.str.contains(r"|".join(bad_list), flags=re.I)

print(df.loc[mask1 & ~mask2, "col1"])
```

Prints:

```
0    John Simon
2    John Bravo
3     Ann Still
Name: col1, dtype: object
```